# How can I do ambient occlusion for simple meshes with few vertices?

Tags: opengl, ambient-occlusion

I want to do ambient occlusion for some simple buildings.

Since simple buildings have very few vertexes, how can I get good results? Is it possible with a per-vertex AO implementation?

[image]

Comment: Try [this article](http://0fps.net/2013/07/03/ambient-occlusion-for-minecraft-like-worlds/). You can also look into SSAO.